# React Express js auth

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

We are trying to make course share option. When we click to the share button it will give a link to the course where people can join.
It after clicking join button user redirect to signup page and register after that we verify user and after verifying user it will redirect to the specific program
I want to know that what would be the approach to redirect the user. Should I add one more field in mongodb with redirect url

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

use react router dom to redirect in client side

```
const navigate = useNavigate();

useEffect(() => {
   if (isLoggedIn){
      return navigate("/courses");
   }
},[isLoggedIn]);
```